# What is the current status of AIA (Authority Information Access) support in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, digital-certificate

The title says it all.  I have found several discussions of AIA, but I have not found any recent statement that it is (or will be) supported, either for server side or client side certificates.  This is important because we have a smart card project that will affect thousands of people with certs that are not in the standard list of CA roots, and/or  intermediates, but does have a valid AIA.  It is not practical to require our users to add the missing certificates; too many, too low-tech.  Of course the certificates work just fine with IE and Chrome.

Do I have to tell people not to use Firefox?  :-(

Comment: The question is not related to programming. SuperUser or some Mozilla forums should be a better place to ask.

Comment: The bug on file is: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=399324 (Please note that bugzilla is not a discussion forum; I'm giving this link so you can track the progress, if any). It also contains some rational by the developers as to the potential (privacy) issues of AIA.